# How to set label text bold in delphi Xe8

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, tlabel

How can you set a TLabel to Bold and back to normal runtime in Delphi XE8 firemonkey multi device project?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
label.TextSettings.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
```

Also tried:

```
label.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `label.StyledSettings.Style` false, then it will follow the `Fontstyle` settings.

[image]

Here a sample code to toggle `StyledSettings.Style`with in code (although I don't remember that I've ever played back and forth with these. For me it's more a one time setup at start).

```
procedure TForm6.Button9Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TStyledSetting.Style in Label3.StyledSettings then
    Label3.StyledSettings := Label3.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Style]
  else
    Label3.StyledSettings := Label3.StyledSettings + [TStyledSetting.Style]
end;
```

And to toggle the `TextSettings.Font.Style`

```
procedure TForm6.Button8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TFontStyle.fsBold in Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style then
    Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style - [TFontStyle.fsBold]
  else
    Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style := Label3.TextSettings.Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
end;
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Can only change label.styledsettings and not styledsettings.style

Comment: I can't check with XE8 right now. Do you mean that the Object Inspector doesn't show you the `StyledSettings` in XE8?

Comment: Ow yes it shows in object inspector but i wanted to do it runtime. But thanks that works only how i do change the text to normal again after changing it to bold?

Comment: What you can do in design-time can also be done in run-time. Changing it back works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```pascal
Label1.Font.Style := [fsBold];
```

I used delphi 10.4.